# Javascript puting only once value to array

Tags: android

How I can put only once one value to array? I wana do something like that:

```
array.put("banana");
array.put("apples");
array.put("banana");
array.put("raspberry");
```

and the result should be banana, apples and raspberry
Thanks!

Comment: use a Set, that's what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
var duplicates = [1,3,4,2,1,2,3,8];
var uniques = duplicates.unique();
```

Comment: the tag in the question suggests it is related to Android, not javascript.